# Plotting a pyplot graph with a single column of Data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, rows

I have a data of CSV format which consists of 9 columns and over 900000 rows. What should I do in order to plot the graph for a single column from a particular range of rows? eg: To plot the graph from 12th to the 29000th row. I had previously used pyplot to plot the graph and pandas to read the csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your column is named `Column`. Then you would slice your dataframe and create a plot using:

```
plt.plot(df.loc[11:28999, 'Column'])
```

Without more information it's difficult to give a more complete answer.

To accept user input for these columns, simply do:

```
start_row = input('Please enter starting row: ')
end_row = input('Please enter ending row: ')

plt.plot(df.loc[start_row:end_row, 'Column'])
```

Comment: `df.loc[11:28999] `, index starts from "0".

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually got the result but is there any way that I can give this range of rows in an input form? Since I am unable to do it inside the plot

Comment: @SrivatsanM If you mean accepting user input, it's indeed possible. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Oh thanks. I didn't know that you can slice using objects